# node.js | ensureAdmin middleware function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a middleware function that should check in a db if the logged in user has the role = 2 before allowing access to the requested page. If the user does not have the role = 2 he should be redirected to the home page (/). I wrote following function to achieve that:

```
isAdmin = function(req, res, callback) {
    let Users = require('./models/users');
    Users.findOne({ 'steam.id': req.user.steam.id }, 'role', function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            return callback(err, false);
        } else {
            if(data.steam.role === undefined || data.steam.role != 2) {
                return callback(null, false);
            } else {
                if(data.steam.role === 2){
                    return callback(null, true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

The following function gets placed in the app.get(/admin) part of my routes file

```
function ensureAdmin(req, res, next) {

    if (isAdmin()) {
        return next();
    }
    console.log(colors.red('[ATTENTION] ') + colors.red('A non admin tried to access admin-only pages'));
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

**app.get:**

```
app.get('/admin', ensureAuthenticated, ensureAdmin, function(req, res){
    res.send('Admin panel!');
});
```

When I try to access the /admin page I just get a **ReferenceError: isAdmin is not defined**. Possibly there are more errors after this one that I can't solve so it would be great if anyone could tell me what I did wrong and fix the code if he wants. I am a node.js beginner :)

**EDIT (new code):**

```
module.exports = function(isAdmin){
    var isAdmin = function(req, res, callback) {

        if(req.user.steam.role === undefined || req.user.steam.role != 2){
            return callback(null, false);
        } else {
            if(req.user.steam.role === 2){
                return callback(null, true);
            }
        }

    };
}
```

.

```
let isAdmin = require('../functions/isAdmin');
function ensureAdmin(req, res, next) {

    if(isAdmin()) {
        return next();
    }

}
```

Comment: isAdmin is asynchronous you can't just call ` if(isAdmin()) {}`

Comment: If you already have a user loaded onto the request object, why do you have to check their role in the database? Shouldn't you be able to check req.user.steam.role?

Comment: Thanks Paul, I implemented your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an export on your function isAdmin if you are in different files and do return that function as it's async

```
var isAdmin = function(req, res, callback) {
let Users = require('./models/users');
return Users.findOne({ 'steam.id': req.user.steam.id }, 'role', function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        return callback(err, false);
    } else {
        if(data.steam.role === undefined || data.steam.role != 2) {
            return callback(null, false);
        } else {
            if(data.steam.role === 2){
                return callback(null, true);
            }
        }
    }
});
};
export default isAdmin
```

Also, the call needs to be thenable

```
function ensureAdmin(req, res, next) {

 isAdmin().then(response =>  {
    next();
 });

}
```

I noticed that you have written console.log res.redirect which will not make sense after calling `next()` in middleware. You can shift this `console.log()` prior to the `next()` call. Avoid `res.redirect()` in middleware

Last, Assuming that you are doing an import of a file as well as mentioned by @hansmaad

Comment: Thank you for your advice :) I took the comment of Paul into consideration and removed the db query. I think now my code doesn't need then() anymore right? I have edited my original post with my edited code. Could you look if everything is alright? Somehow I get redirected to my homepage even though I have the role=2.

Comment: That was a great input from Paul. Missed out in a hurry. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Frist you have to [`export`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) your isAdmin function from the file where it is implemented

```
export default isAdmin
```

and then `require` it in the file where you want to use it

```
const isAdmin = require('../middlewares/isAdmin');  // wherever you've put this file
```

As your isAdmin function is async and returns a promise, you have to call `next()` when this promise resolved.

```
isAdmin().then(() => next(), () => res.redirect('/'));
```